# I'm trying to plot a graph but matrix dimensions don't agree in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, plot

So I'm trying to plot a graph and this is my code so far

```
T=10; %set the values given to us
t(1)=0;
delta=0.01;
mu=0.05;
sigma=linspace(0,1,10001); %set the spacing for sigma
v=zeros(length(sigma),T); %set the xeros
k=1;
for sigma=linspace(0.01,1,1000)
t(k)=k*delta; 
eta=randn(1); %define eta
S(2)=1+mu*delta+sigma*sqrt(delta)*eta; %set S
S(T+1)=S(10)+mu*delta*S(10)+sigma*sqrt(delta)*eta*S(10);
end
t(10000)=1; %set the rounding error
plot (S,sigma) %plot the graph
xlabel 'S' %label the axis
ylabel 'sigma'
```

I've tried using . to satisfy inner matrix dimensions (for S) but this hasn't worked. I've been going round in circles for a while now and can't figure it out.

Comment: Why dont you try to debug your code line by line. As a starting point: In your for loop, dont loop over all values but set `sigma` to just one value, e.g. `for sigma=0.01`. If you do this execute your code and see which error you get and what the reason for that is. Check whether all variables (index vectors) exist and which value they have. Additionally you should inform yourself how to ask a question [ask], we have no idea what you are trying to calculate, so we can't really help you as we dont know what the desired output is.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and analyzed the problem, and I have a few doubts about it. It would be so helpful to know what problem are you trying to solve. But, focusing on what we have, one of the things I've seen is about the iteration. It doesn´t make sense to me, you've used a ***for*** iteration structure with the sigma condition. That's ok, let's see step by step what's happening:

```
for sigma=linspace(0.01,1,1000)
    t(k)=k*delta;
    eta=randn(1); %define eta
    S(2)=1+mu*delta+sigma*sqrt(delta)*eta; %set S
    S(T+1)=S(10)+mu*delta*S(10)+sigma*sqrt(delta)*eta*S(10);
end
```

First of all, you can define ***t(k)*** of the iteration, as the value doesn´t change with it. Next, you've written ***S(2)*** and ***S(T+1)***, here, you're doing an iteration, that's correct, but you're overwriting the values over and over again each loop, so you're overwriting some values of a matrix ***S***. About ***S***, it could be helpful to preassign the expected size in memory, you can use:

```
S=zeros(i,j); % Being i and j, the matrix dimensions.
```

or simply, as some people like, declaring the variable (not necessary in Matlab):

```
S=[];
```

This depends on the problem you're solving. I really want to help you, but I need to know more about the problem. I don't know your working method or how you face your problems, but what I always do is solve it first in a piece of paper, or if it's a numerical problem of some kind and you can't solve it, then just sketch the ideas you have and check things like the coherence in matrix operations (related to matrix sizes), and those kind of things...

Hope I've been helpful, and have a nice day :)